# Single sign from a windows service

Tags: azure, iis, single-sign-on, openid-connect

My company utilizes single sign on using a few different providers (Azure, Integrated Windows Authentication, Open ID Connect) exc.. We have a windows service that runs on the clients server and makes web service calls on a regular basis to our web application. Currently we suggest the client install a Non SSO instance for the windows application to make calls into the web service.

My question is there a good way for the window service to makes calls into the SSO instance of our web application that will work for all SSO providers.

Comment: a good way is to assign an identity to each Windows Service. This way, you'll who is calling your API, and can revoke access if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a problem unless you design for it architecturally:

- Your web app should call a Web API
- The Windows Service should call the same Web API
- It is not standard for a Windows Service to call a Web app

In OAuth terms:

- A web app will use Authorization Code Flow and get a token containing the logged in user id (sub claim)
- A Windows service will use Client Credentials Flow and get a token that only contains a client id and no user id
- Your Web API will need to deal with both cases

It feels like the client should only use one fixed SSO provider for the Windows service. Either that or you work out which one is used at runtime based on the iss (issuer) claim in the access token.